# How do I subtract two data frames of unequal length

Tags: r, dataframe

```
x<-c(1:5)
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
df1<- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

x<-c(1:10)
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
df2<- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

I can set get the difference between these data frames with

```
setdiffDF(df1, df2)
```

What I want to do is take this result away from df2 so I'm left with df1 and df2 matching exactly

Thanks

Comment: So should your resulting df2 be identical with df1?

Comment: Can't you simply take a copy of df1 as df2?

Comment: Also, do you mean `setdiff` from `base` R or is `setdiffDF` a differnt function from another package? Maybe `intersect(df1, df2)` is also interesting for your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use base R `merge` function too

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "y")
```

Or you can merge by both `y` and `x`

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("y", "x"))
```

In case you want to keep all values in `df1` regardless if they all matched to `df2` you can do

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("y", "x"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `intersect` from `dplyr` (not to be confused with `base::intersect`).

```
> library(dplyr)
> intersect(df1, df2)
##   x y
## 1 1 a
## 2 2 b
## 3 3 c
## 4 4 d
## 5 5 e
```